# Можно ли получить доступ к объекту функции в явном виде?

Tags: javascript, объекты, this

Как можно  получить доступ к объекту функции в явном виде? Вот код:

```js
function table(){
  this.spoons=10;
}

document.write(typeof(table)+"<br>")    // function
table.call(table)    //указываю в явном виде, на что будет указывать this в foo
document.write(table.hasOwnProperty("spoons")+"<br>")    //true
document.write(table.spoons+"<br>")    //обращаемся как к обычному свойству объекта
```

Я создал переменную `spoons`, предположительно добавив её в объект, хм НО В КАКОЙ? Ведь `typeof(table)===function`, ну а бредовая и не рабочая команда `typeof(table.call(foo))`(с помощью которой я предположил, что смогу докопаться до объекта функции) - бредовая, и не работает!

Получается "объект функции" это как Йети? Все в курсе, но никто не видел?

Или есть всё таки способ отобразить `typeof(table)===object`?

Просто все,и по всюду говорят, что функции это объекты в js, ну вот и стало интересно! Спасибо!

П.С.: table функция и table объект связанны хоть как-нибудь?

Comment: `var tbl = new table(); console.log(typeof tbl); console.log(tbl.spoons);`

Comment: Yaant 20 , получается ты создал объект tbl , использовав table (фукнцию) в качестве конструктора, и уже в tbl добавил свойство spoons . читерство ;>

Comment: `console.log(table instanceof Object)`

Comment: Yaant, конструктором для функции table является объект (класс) Object? В принципи я тебя понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае произошла путаница из-за непонимания что именно возвращает `typeof`.

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-typeof-operator), можно заметить, что данный оператор может возвращать строго заданный набор значений.

Конкретно в случае функции используется строка

```
Object (implements [[Call]]) ----> "function"
```

То есть если у **объекта** есть внутреннее поле `[[Call]]` данный оператор вернет `"function"`. Что не делает этот объект менее объектом, чем любой другой.

Таким образом функция `table` - вполне себе является объектом.

Следующим доказательством этого может служить то, что при вызове `table.call(table)`, поле `spoons` добавилось непосредственно в `table`, как в любой другой объект. При этом все еще осталась возможность вызвать `table` как функцию.

---

> Или есть всё таки способ отобразить `typeof(table)===object`?

Такого способа нет, так как нет доступа к внутреннему полю `[[Call]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Действильно, функции в js являются объектами. Чтобы убедиться в этом подручными средствами попробуйте отрыть консоль браузера и добавить определение вашей функции `table`:

```
function table(){
  this.spoons=10;
}
```

Если затем ввести `window` и развернуть глобальный объект, то можно найти свойство `table` предтавленное следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, это обычный объект со своим прототипом и т.п.

Подробнее советую почитать [тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods).